# How could I run ARP in mininet Python script?

Tags: linux, networking, sdn, arp, mininet

I run my topology through this command from a terminal:

```sh
sudo mn --custom=~/myTopo.py --topo=myTopo --mac --arp --switch=ovsk --controller=remote
```

But how could I write the same command in a Python script?

```py
net = Mininet(topo=topo, switch=OVSSwitch, link=TCLink, controller=RemoteController('c0', ip='127.0.0.1', port=6633))
```

This code is written in the script, but I could not include ARP in a Python script. What is the correct syntax to be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```py
net = Mininet(topo=topo, switch=OVSSwitch, link=TCLink, controller=RemoteController('c0', ip='127.0.0.1', port=6633))
net.staticArp()
```

Comment: I'm using this, and it's not working. I included it in my code and `arp -a` is giving no output, just like when I go `sudo mn --topo` etcetera in the CLI without specifying --arp

Comment: @WildWilyWilly Do you have another way to establish ARP?

Comment: sorry mate years have passed and the project is archived